# Configure Database Connections Automatically base on Environment

Tags: php, database, laravel, heroku, database-connection

I know this is so wrong, but I've tried google for this kind of task, and I found nothing.

## Goal

I'm trying to make an `if check`, base on my Laravel environment, I will set the database connection appropriately between my local environment and my Heroku production environment.

```
connections' => [

    'mysql'       => [

        'driver'      => 'mysql',

        if(env('APP_ENV') == 'local'){

            'host'        => env('DB_HOST'),
            'database'    => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket' => env('UNIX_SOCKET'),

        }else{

            'host'     => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["host"],
            'database' => substr(parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["path"], 1),
            'username' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["user"],
            'password' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["pass"],

        }

        'charset'     => 'utf8',
        'collation'   => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'      => '',
        'strict'      => false,
    ]

],
```

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the **[Cascading config](https://github.com/phanan/cascading-config)** package would work great for you. Laravel 4 had something very similar to that package.

You can have a *config.local* folder and *config.production* folder for your Heroku environment.

**Example folder configuration**

```
config/ (production)

├── database.php

config.local/ (local)

├── database.php
```

**config/database.php (production)**

```
...
connections' => [
    'mysql'       => [
        'driver'      => 'mysql',
        'host'        => 'Heroku Host',
        'database'    => 'Heroku Database',
        'username'    => 'Heroku Username',
        'password'    => 'Heroku Password',
        'unix_socket' => 'Heroku Socket',
    ],      
],
...
```

**config.local/database.php (local)**

```
...
connections' => [
    'mysql'       => [
        'driver'      => 'mysql',
        'host'        => env('DB_HOST'),
        'database'    => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    ],      
],
...
```

Comment: Can u please link some example or sample suggestions as part of your answer ?

Comment: @ihue I've added examples, the package has more details of how it works: https://github.com/phanan/cascading-config

Comment: Nice details answer, I like that.

Answer (score 1):

you can define another connection, named for exmaple mysql-heroku, and then in your models you can do `protected $connection = (env('APP_ENV') == 'local') ? 'mysql' : 'mysql-heroku';`.